# DELETE in mysql doesen't work

Tags: python, mysql

good afternoon, 
my query doesen't work but in my opinion is all right can help me somebody ??

```
file = open("c:/seriale.txt","r")
ac = file.read()
import mysql.connector
db = mysql.connector.connect(host="***.***.***.***",  
                 user="***",         
                 passwd="***",  
                 db="DISPOSITIVI")        
    cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute("DELETE FROM `autorizzazioni` WHERE `seriale` LIKE '%s'"%(ac,));
cur.close()
```

thank you

Comment: could you give the result of `print ac` and `print "DELETE FROM \`autorizzazioni\` WHERE \`seriale\` LIKE '%s'"%(ac,)` ?

Comment: " in my opinion is all right" - MySQL disagrees with you.

Comment: Is that the actual indentation you're using? because there's one reason it wouldn't work

Comment: seriale.txt contain only this line: #0008466830#

Comment: You're string formatting values in to your SQL. Don't do that, use placeholders:  `cur.execute("DELETE FROM ... LIKE %s", (ac, ))`. The difference is that you pass your argument sequence as the 2nd argument to execute and you do not need to quote your values yourself.

Comment: mysql not give me any error during the execution

Answer (score 0):

i've solved changing this line:

```
cur.execute("DELETE FROM `autorizzazioni` WHERE `seriale` LIKE '%s'"%(ac,));
```

in this:

```
cur.execute("DELETE FROM autorizzazioni WHERE seriale=%s"%(ac));
```